# Mac MAMP virtual host 404 not found

Tags: macos, mamp, virtualhost

I know it should be very simple and easy, but it's not working for hours :/
I guess it's a custom problem
[image: terminal]

These are my hosts

[image: config]

This is the httpd-config.conf file

And finally this is the destination folder

[image: dest]

Is this info enough? anything I should add?

And this is the error

[image: error]